# When selecting a cell in excel sheet it becomes black

Tags: apache-poi

I am generating excel sheets using Apache POI. When selecting a cell to edit the background of that cell becomes black. I have shared my code and a screenshot of the excel sheet. I didn't set the background to black from anywhere. I have struggled to solve this error for several hours. If anyone know how to solve this please help me.

```
public static void writeSummaryToExcel(int rowNumber, int columnNumber, String workBookName, String sheetName,
                                       int sheetColumnSize, Map<String, List<CommonDto>> appDataMap,
                                       List<CommonDto> summaryData) {
    log.info("AppSummarySheetGenerator - writeSummaryToExcel() called");

    PropertyTemplate propertyTemplate = new PropertyTemplate();

    int rowCount = rowNumber;
    int columnCount = columnNumber;

    try {

        File file = new File(workBookName);

        // initialing workbook and sheet
        workbook = CommonExcelUtils.getWorkbook(file, workBookName);
        Sheet sheet = CommonExcelUtils.getWorkbookSheet(workbook, sheetName, sheetColumnSize, false);
        Row row;
        Cell cell;

        if (workbook != null && sheet != null) {

            //sheet setting up to first sheet
            workbook.setSheetOrder(sheet.getSheetName(), 0);

            // cell styles
            CellStyle fontRightAlignStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            fontRightAlignStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);

            Font boldFont = workbook.createFont();
            boldFont.setBold(true);
            boldFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);

            CellStyle totalLCellStyle = getCommonTotalCellStyle(boldFont);
            totalLCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);

            CellStyle totalRCellStyle = getCommonTotalCellStyle(boldFont);
            totalRCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);

            CellStyle appCategoryStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            appCategoryStyle.setFont(boldFont);
            appCategoryStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            appCategoryStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LEMON_CHIFFON.index);
            appCategoryStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER_SELECTION);

//other code
```

}

```
    private static CellStyle getCommonTotalCellStyle(Font boldFont) {
        CellStyle commonTotalCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        commonTotalCellStyle.setFont(boldFont);
        commonTotalCellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        commonTotalCellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        commonTotalCellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        commonTotalCellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        commonTotalCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        commonTotalCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);
        return commonTotalCellStyle;
   }
```

[Screenshot of the excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJXdP.png)

Comment: The reason for this issue is setting borders. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959440/apache-poi-fills-xssf-cell-with-black-instead-of-desired-custom-color-when-apply

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I am aware of that this may happen is if there is a cell style applied to the cell which has a fill background color set but either not has a fill pattern set or has a no-fill-pattern set. Then the fill background color gets visible if the cell is in edit mode.

Complete example to test:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelCellBackgroudColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx") ) {

   CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
   //style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
   
   //style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
   style.setFillBackgroundColor((short)0);
   
   //style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
   style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.NO_FILL);
   
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellStyle(style);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Here cell `A1` gets black when in edit mode.

Why is that?

In Excel the cell interiors have pattern fill. There fill foreground color is the color of the pattern and  fill background color is the color behind the pattern. If there is a fill background color set but not a pattern, then the background color may get visible.

So the problem is not in the code you have shown. Have a look whether you set `CellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor` somewhere. But maybe the problem is in the source file already. If so, then the source file probably is not created by Excel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check and update you. Thank you so much again